# Ignore All Hotkeys AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

**CODE**

```
currentstring := ""
q::
    ExitApp
return
w::
    MsgBox,,,Hello`, World!,3
return
e::
    MsgBox,,,Hello World,3
return
r::
    InputBox, currentstring
    *::
    return
return
t::
    MsgBox,,,%currentstring%,3
return
```

But when I am in the InputBox and I press `q`,`w`,`e`,`r`, or `t`, it executes the code before the return, even though I already override the hotkeys by `*::`.

Is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*::` is not a "catch all" hotkey, it just fires when it detects an asterisk (normally Shift+8).

To achieve your desired effect, you should activate the hotkeys based on the active window.

#### Working Example

If the active window is an `InputBox` (`ahk_class #32270`), disable the hotkeys, but don't block their native function (the `~` prefix). If not the `InputBox`, bind the hotkeys as desired.

```
#SingleInstance force
currentstring := ""
return ; end auto-execute section

#IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770 ; If an InputBox window, restore default key function
~q::
~w::
~e::
~r::
~t::
  return

#IfWinActive ; If anything else
q::
    ExitApp
return
w::
    MsgBox,,,Hello`, World!,3
return
e::
    MsgBox,,,Hello World,3
return
r::
    InputBox, currentstring
return
t::
    MsgBox,,,%currentstring%,3
return
```

#### Notes:

- It is considered best practice to only bind the hotkeys you need, not to everything.
- To determine a Window's properties (class, id, etc.), you can use the *Active Window Info* or *Window Spy* tool bundled with AutoHotKey. It can also be launched from the system tray icon of a running script if `Menu, Tray, NoStandard` has not been used.

Comment: Thank you! What does #SingleInstance force do?

Comment: Makes sure that only one of this program is running at a time. By default whenever I'm working with hotkeys it's useful to make sure you've only got one version running at a time. [`#SingleInstance`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_SingleInstance.htm)

Comment: Okay! Normally it just gives a warning and I shut down the older instance. Thanks for the tip, though!